# How to prevent loop animation to pause

Tags: jquery, animation

(coffee break)

### [THE ANIMATION IN QUESTION](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/pJfZT/1/)

Having this:

```
$('.cloud').each(function(){
    var cloud = $(this);

    function move(){
        mL = Math.round(Math.random()*60);
        mT = Math.round(Math.random()*60);
        cloud.animate({left: mL, top: mT },2000);  
    }           
    move();

    setInterval(function() {
        move();
    }, 2000);

});
```

As you can see in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/pJfZT/1/) the squares **pause** any movement after **2** seconds. And than they continue with the loop. What's the way to just make them roll around without the pause/restart feel? Thank you very many :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.cloud').each(function(){
    var cloud = $(this);

    function move(){
        mL = Math.round(Math.random()*60);
        mT = Math.round(Math.random()*60);
        // set callback upon complete animation
        // set easing to linear to prevent acceleration and deceleration of animation
        cloud.animate({left: mL, top: mT },2000,'linear',move);  
    }           
    move();

   // get rid of timer

});
```

Comment: No. Ok, now I see the timer it's worth nothing, but your example results THE SAME as I posted above. Clouds after 2 secs STOP their movements to restart again. Same thing.

Comment: Maight be **stop** is not the right word so I changed it to 'pause'.

Comment: you can use linear easing on animation so that it does not accelerate and decelerate at the start and end of the transition - see: http://jsfiddle.net/pJfZT/2/

Comment: easings are a great feature of the jquery animations. You can download plugins that have more easings, bounce is especially useful

Comment: It seems like there are default easings (without the ose of jQ UI) what are the defaults? (like just say 'linear', what are the others?)

Comment: only linear and swing are default. The easings library is not JQ UI specific - there are good sets of easing functions as standalone JQ plugin.